# Dynamic stored Procedure pulling data from 3 different table

Tags: t-sql

i have three different sql query, and i want to convert it in single stored Procedure.
based on passing parameter we can get output from either 1st, 2nd or 3rd.

1st query:

```
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, CITY FROM LOCATION WHERE REGION <> 3
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, CITY FROM LOCATION WHERE REGION = 3
```

3rd query:

```
SELECT NAME, OFFICE_ADDRESS, RES_ADDRESS,PROPERTY_TAX FROM COUNTRY WHERE REGION = 'ZUR'
```

May anyone please help me how to acheive this.

Thanks a ton

Comment: Using Case in your procedure, you can fire your specific select query. https://sqlschool.modeanalytics.com/intermediate/case/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the first two selects it makes sense to make a `IF` statement. But not to the last because the number of fields is different.

Even if most of the columns on `LOCATION` and `COUNTRY` have the same meaning that can add problems in maintenance and add complexity to your code.

Also using more than a table for same purpose is a symptom of bad design.

```
IF (@FLAG = 1)
BEGIN

   SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, CITY FROM LOCATION WHERE REGION != 3

END
ELSE
BEGIN

   SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, CITY FROM LOCATION WHERE REGION = 3

END
```

Create another method/SP to fetch the data on `COUNTRY`

Note: for the last MS SQL Server versions `IF` is the recomended way for improve performance. Also using `CASE` statements can mean it need to eval the `REGION` column for each row in the table.

Note: Learn about **parameter sniffing** to avoid it. Conditionals messing with SP behaviour are a good way to get parameter sniffing problems.